# THREE.js CSS2DRenderer - How to save ordinary and CSS2D image as a single .jpg file?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

Using the code listed below...

(1) I have been able to save ordinary rendered `THREE.js` scenes as `.jpg` files;

(2) I have also been able to use `CSS2DRenderer` to "render" CSS2D labels on top of (not "onto")  the canvas;

(3) Next I want to save the `CSS2DRenderer`-rendered overlay image as a second `.jpg` file;

But I get the error:- `TypeError: labelRenderer.domElement.toDataURL is not a function`.

I am thinking that maybe it is not possible to export from CSS2D?

(4) Ideally I want to save the combined (ordinary and CSS2D overlay) onscreen image as a single `.jpg` file.

Code:-

```
// GLOBALS

// INITIATION

    var MyContainer = document.getElementById( "for_3JS" );
    MyContainer.innerHTML = "";

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true , preserveDrawingBuffer: true} );   
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( wwww, hhhh );

    MyContainer.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); 

    var labelRenderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
    labelRenderer.setSize( wwww, hhhh );     
    labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
    
    MyContainer.appendChild( labelRenderer.domElement ); 

// ANIMATION & RENDERING

    renderer.render     ( scene, camera );
    labelRenderer.render( scene, camera );

// ONCLICK
            
    var strMime = "image/jpg";
    
    //... THIS WORKS OK (but NO LABELS):- 
    var imgDataA = renderer.domElement.toDataURL( strMime );            
    
    //... THIS FAILS  with:- TypeError: labelRenderer.domElement.toDataURL is not a function.           
    var imgDataB = labelRenderer.domElement.toDataURL( strMime );   
    
    //... save as file (imgDataA only at present).
    var fileURL = imgDataA;//imgDataB
            //...from http://muaz-khan.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/save-files-on-disk-using-javascript-or.html
    var Fsave = document.createElement('a'); //... creates an html <a> anchor object.                       
            
    document.body.appendChild( Fsave ); //... for Firefox, not needed in Opera (?)
    Fsave.style     = "display: none";
    Fsave.href      = fileURL;
    Fsave.target    = '_blank';
    Fsave.download  = filename || 'unknown';
    Fsave.click();
    document.body.removeChild( Fsave );
```

Answer (score 1):

> (2) I have also been able to use CSS2DRenderer to render CSS2D labels onto the canvas;

I'm afraid this formulation is not correct since your are not rendering "onto the canvas" when using `CSS2DRenderer` or `CSS3DRenderer`. You actually put HTML elements on top of the canvas and assign them a respective 2D or 3D transformation.

Hence, it is not possible to use `toDataURL()` to save the output of `WebGLRenderer` AND `CSS2DRenderer` into an image.

> I have inspected .domElement in the debugger but cannot see toDataURL even for renderer.domElement.

The method definitely exists when using `WebGLRenderer`, see https://jsfiddle.net/dxmrvzw6/.

Comment: Thanks for (a) the semantic clarification "on top of" instead of "onto" and (b) showing that the `toDataURL` method exists for `WebGLRenderer`. I will correct these details in the question.  Do you have any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: TBH, I think it's not feasible to easily implement this. At least I'm not aware of an approach.

Comment: Googling around, so far I've located `https://html2canvas.hertzen.com` but I'm not sure it will handle CSS2D rendition.